# Google search keywords

Tags: search, keyword

I want to search from Google.com about some information from particular sites. for example

I want to search php from only w3school.com and php.net. I can use `site:w3school.com php`

but how can i use two websites

Comment: If you are only searching 2 sites, w3schools shouldn't be one of them: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` with the `site` option

[Hyperlink: Stack Overflow Similar Response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/search-on-specific-sites-only)

Comment: thanks fro the answer. but its not working. because it takes the result from all of the sites. I want only take from two sites. for example

site:w3school.com or php.net mysql_connect

Comment: I found the answer myself
`site:en.wikipedia.org OR site:w3schools.com PHP Mysql`
You should insert `site:` fore each site you want to add. 

Hope this will helps someone